# Popular questions when filtering by tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

After searching for and selecting a tag I am correctly redirected to the "New questions" tab (under questions) with filter: custom tags, the tag I selected in the filter field and its description underneath. Questions are also filtered by the selected tag. If I then navigate to the "popular" tab and select "hot" (which is default) no "filter" drop down exists, and questions are not filtered by the tag I have selected, however I can still see the tag description over the question list.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on a tag from your favorites tags on the right hand screen.
2. Click on the popular tab.

[image]

**Edit:** Another aspect of this issue is that although when I am redirected to the "New questions" tab after a tag selection I get the questions filtered by custom tag, if I navigate to any of the other two tabs and then back to the "new" tab I no longer see the filtered questions and instead only see the selected tag's description. What is more, I don't even see the "filter" drop down in this case.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select a tag from the favorite tags or from the tags page. The user is redirected to the "new" questions tab where questions are filtered by the selected tag as expected.
   [image: Questions filtered correctly]
2. Click the "need answer" tab. The questions that need answer are displayed filtered by the selected tag.
3. Go back to the "new" tab. The selected tag description is still there, however questions are no longer filtered and the "filter" drop down is no longer visible.
   [image: Questions no longer filtered]

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue and edited a screenshot of the reproduction in to your question.

Comment: @TravisJ That's great, thanks. I'm ashamed to say that I found the issue to be so obvious that it didn't event occur to me to include a screenshot...

Comment: The second issue you show is actually related to the recommended selection. There was a feature request to allow recommended to filter by tag and I believe it was marked as pending. For now, the recommended selection cannot be filtered by tag and that is why it does not show up.

Comment: @TravisJ But if that is the case then why do I still see the tag description? Plus I would expect to not see the recommended questions but to still see all questions (filtered by tag) when I go back to the "new" tab. Otherwise the way that a tag is added or removed as I navigate between tabs is just weird.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed and is being deployed.